# Why is HttpContext.Current.Profile NULL? How does it get a value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, asp.net-membership

I inherited MOSS code which implements a custom `profile` provider. The setup seems to be okay (provider & web.config).

A user can login, however, after logging in, the `HttpContext.Current.Profile` object is null. Why is it null? How/When is is supposed to get a value?

`HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` has a value after loggin in.

Comment: what u want to do, and where code is executed?

Answer (score 0):

Mike Feng says:

> Through Profile provider you have to load the Profile information from
>   SQL server profile table .
>
> Pass the UserName parameter in GetProfile function of WebProfile class
>   . This class is generated by a tool .

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/netfxbcl/thread/af78e6c0-03f5-4f2d-ad07-dd2a57304377

Answer (score 0):

Try ProfileBase.Create(username, isAuthenticated)

```
public static System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase Create(string username, bool isAuthenticated)
    Member of System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase

Summary:
Used by ASP.NET to create an instance of a profile for the specified user name. Takes a parameter indicating whether the user is authenticated or anonymous.

Parameters:
username: The name of the user to create a profile for.
isAuthenticated: true to indicate the user is authenticated; false to indicate the user is anonymous.

Returns:
A System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase object that represents the profile for the specified user.
```